# JSON.stringify on Dynatree.toDict works in Development environment but not on other machines

Tags: json, dynatree, stringify

Very new to WCF and almost got everything to work doing POST from JQuery to WCF. I thought?

The Jquery is processing a DynaTree and gets the latest dictionary which needs to be serialized in order to perform a successful post.
When I run Visual Studio, it works fine. When I access the site from my development machine - not in debug mode - it also works fine.  But when accessing the site from any other machine siting on the same domain within the WLAN, it fails. 
var dict = $("#tree").dynatree("getTree").toDict();

The line in particular that fails is JSON.stringify(dict);

The alerts shows an object coming through and hence toDict() works fine. However, when JSON tries to serialize it, fails.

This serialized data will be my post data to WCF handle. There is nothing wrong in WCF, the call to WCF is never made as the code fails one line above.

Need help.

Comment: Just an update to this issue.  It works with FireFox on other machines.  Wondering if this is all about proxy settings browser specific. IE is firm standard. Thoughts on what to look for?

Comment: Further update: All browser works except IE and also finding that IE is fine when entering IP address instead of the machine name. Hoping to figure this one out soon, by checking on IE settings and with the help of network folks.

Comment: Consider this question as duplicate to and that was answered on :  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21474658/on-a-postback-the-ajax-call-to-a-wcf-webservice-uses-postdata-but-the-json-strin