# On a postback the ajax call to a WCF webservice uses postData but the JSON.stringify fails on mainly IE though works fine in Chrome and FireFox

Tags: wcf, ajax, json

I have a Dynatree and `onSelect: function(select, node)`, I call a routine SaveUserTree()`.

In this routine, I get the latest `toDict()` on the tree which then is passed to a JSON stringify function.  The resultant postData is then sent to the WCF service call.
However, the JSON.stringify fails on IE but works in both Chrome and FireFox.
The error is 'undefined' and some other info using F12 debugger reveals:

> JSON is undefined
>   number -2146823279
>   name   "TypeError"

```
function SaveUserTree(treeNode){
    var dict = $("#tree").dynatree("getTree").toDict();

    postData = JSON.stringify(dict);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "TodoTreeService.svc/SaveTree/New?Name=" + $("#hdnUserFile").val(),
        //contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        data: postData, 
        success: function (arg){
            alert("SUCCESS - " + JSON.stringify(arg));                   
        },
        error: function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError) {
            alert("ERROR - " + JSON.stringify(xhr.responseText));
        }  
    });

}
```

Please help as this is a biggie.

Answer (score 2):

This will be surely because you are using older version of IE which does not support JSON. So use the <strike>[json2.js](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js/blob/master/json2.js) fallback by Douglas Crockford</strike> [json3.js](http://bestiejs.github.io/json3/) fallback. Just refer the library in your page like this

```
<script type='text/javascript' 
        src='//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/json3/3.3.0/json3.min.js'>
</script>
```